# Laravel 5 nested relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 tables, with:

```
User: id | name
Products: id | name | user_id
Tracks: user_id | product_id
```

Relationships between these models (tables) are:

```
//User.php*************************************************
public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
public function track() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Track');
}


//Product.php*************************************************
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
public function track() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Track');
}


//Track.php*************************************************
 public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Track table is used if user want to track the product. Some kind of bookmark.

So, when I'am on product page, `$product = App\Product::find(1)`, if I want to echo the user name, I do `$product->user()->name`, but if I want to know if the user already tracking the current product, when I do `$product->user()->track()->get()` I receive this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::track()
```

If I do `$product->user()->with('track')->get()`, I don't get an error, but I get User Object which it do not contain info if the user already tracking the product.

How can I know if user is already tracking the product?

Comment: Using the magic accessors for the relationships (`$product->user`) will give you a model of that type whereas the methods (`$product->user()`) give you an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Query\Buider` The builder method doesn't have the method `track()` but the model does. So `$product->user->track()` would allow you to use that method. Or even `$product->user->track` would work.

Comment: Have you tried? `$product->track->user`

Comment: Great. I've learn something new. Thanks. I've tried that and I have noticed that if I do App\Product::find(1)->user->track it will bring all the products bookmarked by the user that posted the product. The query lunched is select * from tracks where tracks.user_id = 4. 4 is user id that posted the product. That is the first problem. Second is that I want to now if logged user, not the one that posted the product, is tracking the product. Sorry for the incomplete information in my question.

Comment: @Alexandros $product->track->user returns an error: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, some of your relationship should be like these

Product.php

```
public function track() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Track');
}
```

Track.php

```
public function product() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

now to check if a user is tracking a product

```
$product = App\Product::find($id);
$product->user->track()->where('product_id', $product->id)->first();
```

another way

```
$user = App\User::find($id);
$user->track()->where('product_id', $product->id)->first();
```

And to check if logged in user is tracking the product, you can get the logged in user by Auth::user() , so

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->track()->where('product_id', $product->id)->first();
```

Comment: It not working correctly. When I test Auth::user()->trackProduct()->where('product_id', '6')->first() it returns null, because the formed query is this: select `tracks`.*, `products`.`user_id` from `tracks` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `tracks`.`product_id` where `products`.`user_id` = '1' and `product_id` = '6' limit 1; Where clause should begin with `tracks`.`user_id` = "1", not with `products`.`user_id` ="1"

Comment: set the Auth::user() to a variable then use trackProduct method like in the answer

Comment: It seems that if in User.php I change the relation to simple hasMany('App\Track') then $user->track()->where('product_id', '6')->first() is returning the correct result. But this is the correct way to do it?

Comment: yes it is correct , i actually over complicated it, sometimes the solution is very simple but we think in hard way, i'm gonna edit my answer

Comment: Thank you! I've done also a little improvement over code readability. I've created a method inside User.php like so: public function isTrackingProduct($productId) { if($this->track()->where('product_id', $productId)->first() != null) return true; else return false; } And now I can simply check like so: $user->isTrackingProduct($product->id) or App\User::user()->isTrackingProduct($product->id), for the current logged user.